# mongoDb query to search values using $in and $or?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

var norm = [ 'may',
  'funny',
  'top funny',
  'dinner',
  'dog',
  'hello',
  'flo',
  'sake',
  'hai',
  'video',
  'rhymes',
  'fine',
  'good',
  'public',
  'testing',
  'irish',
  'hii',
  'babies',
  'coffee',
  'happy',
  'working',
  'comedy',
  'india',
  'best',
  'top',
  'feelings',
  'krishna',
  'test' ]

```
schema.find( { $or: [ {"head":{"$in":norm}}, {"key":{"$in":norm}} ],"privacy":{"$ne":"Private"} },function(err,res){});
```

i have to list the result in ascending order as per the norm but i didnt get the exact result from the above query.

Comment: what results are we talking

Comment: i need to search for the each term present in norm with both head and key field in my schema and list out the result ?

Comment: you know that projection wont work right?

Comment: projection? what does it mean?

Comment: What is your mongodb version ? Do you mean sort  part is not working when you say you don't get the exact result ?

Comment: got result ..Thank all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query wont ever work, this is the format for find schema. `db.collection.find(query, projection)` where projection are the fields you wish to return from the query if it is a success. Also in your query is both `norm` is a array right?

Your is wrong: `schema.find( { $or: [ {"head":{"$in":norm}}, {"key":{"$in":norm}} ],"privacy":{"$ne":"Private"} },function(err,res){});`.

This `"privacy":{"$ne":"Private"}` is not included in the query that is why, it is in the projection section.

should be something like this : `schema.find( { $or: [ {"head":{"$in":norm}}, {"key":{"$in":norm}}],"privacy":{"$ne":"Private"}});`.

Here is a elegant way for this query.

```
Schema.find( { $or: [ {"head":{"$in":norm}}, {"key":{"$in":norm}}]).where("privacy").ne("Private").exec(function(err,doc){});
```

Comment: firstly are you using mongoose for the driver interface?

Comment: also that should be the schema should be a model instance of the schema.'

Comment: ya but i am getting the same results using your query as i got before.

Comment: explain what you mean

Comment: alright, so what is the current display vserus the desired diaplay, show here. probably your query in incorrect, though it is syntactically correct.